# How to convert decimal number to string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my code for `Cost` i have taken `Decimal` datatype but i want to convert `decimal` into the `string` so how can i do.

```
public ActionResult SaveService(string ServiceName, decimal cost)
            {
                int result = RankedServices.Business.Provider.ServicesCriteria.SaveService(ServiceName, cost);
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Comment: cost.ToString(), or Convert.ToString(cost)

Comment: plz show in my code how i have to write

Comment: @Nandkishor Really? You couldn't take the comment and think for a moment before applying it to your code? There's really only one place that comment would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
cost.ToString("0.##");
```

Complete Code,

```
public ActionResult SaveService(string ServiceName, decimal cost)
{
 int result = RankedServices.Business.Provider.ServicesCriteria.SaveService(ServiceName, cost.ToString("0.##"));
  return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: this is comment not answer

Comment: @viveknuna this could be an answer bro and i posted here since OP wanted to apply to his code

Comment: you should not promote spoonfeeding just to get good reputation.

Comment: @viveknuna It cannot be called so, btw it does not deserve a downvote

Comment: cost.ToString("0.##"); will rounding the value if there's more digit than 2 after the decimal point. I think he just want to make the decimal string.

Comment: Its not about happy or being sad bro, be fair :), btw thanks

Comment: You certainly shouldn't have answered this question. It's just pathetic. Google the title of the question and you'll get the `ToString()` function. Don't say this site is for people who can't use Google.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cost.ToString()` to convert the decimal value to string.

Like if you need to pass the string format of the decimal cost see the following code snippet.

```
public ActionResult SaveService(string ServiceName, decimal cost)
            {
                int result = RankedServices.Business.Provider.ServicesCriteria.SaveService(ServiceName, cost.ToString());
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my = DoFormat(123.0);
```

with `DoFormt`being something like:

```
public static string DoFormat( double myNumber )
var s = string.Format("{0:0.00}", myNumber);

if ( s.EndsWith("00") )
{
    return ((int)myNumber).ToString();
}
else
{
    return s;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it might be solve your problem:

```
stringVal = System.Convert.ToString(decimalVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write

string val=Convert.ToString(DecimalValue);
OR
string val=DecimalValue.ToString();